# Save the user cookie authentication

Tags: express, parse-platform

I'm creating a web application using parse and express. I need an user control access.

In my local env it works. But when I deploy in Parse, the cookie doesn't save.

```
var express = require('express');
var parseExpressCookieSession = require('parse-express-cookie-session');
var app = express();

...    

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.cookieParser('MY_SECRET'));  
app.use(parseExpressCookieSession({ cookie: { maxAge: 3600000 } }));
app.use(express.cookieSession());
app.use(express.methodOverride());

app.use(function(req, res, next){
  // set logged user
  res.locals.user = Parse.User.current();
  res.locals.messages = req.session.messages || (req.session.messages = []);
  req.session.messages = [];

  /**
   *  {
   *    type: "message, success or error",
   *    message: "the message"
   *  }
   */
  req.flash = function(message) {
    req.session.messages.push(message);
  }

  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Parse JS Doc explain this:

> This middleware only works when your app is accessed through an HTTPS connection. You can use the parseExpressHttpsRedirect middleware to force all requests to your website to be HTTPS.

http://parse.com/docs/js/symbols/parseExpressCookieSession.html

I wasn't using the parseExpressHttpsRedirect.